# Merge k unsorted lists into one and sort them and then separate them into k sorted lists?

Tags: algorithm, np

Say I have k unsorted list and I want to merge them into one list so that I could run my sorting algorithm on them, and then I need to separate this large merged list to get k sorted list. How could I keep track of which element belong to which list so that I can separate this merged list correctly? It needs to be done in linear time

Comment: If you try to seperate large merged list to get back k sorted lists, it won't make any sense to merge them and sort them. Sort each sub-list individually, without merging.

Comment: If the range of elements is not specified, then it will take atleast `nlogn` time to sort the elements. It cannot be done in linear time.

Comment: @taurus05 It's an algorithm problem, like I am only allowed to perform sorting once so I have to merge all lists into one list so that I can sort them. However, sorting is not the problem here, my task is to merge k list and then separate them in linear time. Let's say I have k list and each list has m elements.

Comment: Convert those elements into objects.

Comment: How about priority queues?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have `n` elements

Initialize:
For each element in each list add a `int` that says to which list it belongs. Iterate over all `O(n)`.

Merge:
For each list go to its end and make it point to the beginning of the next one. Total time `O(n)`.

Break:
Create `k` pointers - the start of the new `k lists`.
Iterate over the sorted list and for each element in the list copy it to the end of the list it says it belongs to from the new `k lists`.
We can remember the end of each of the new lists so it would take `O(1)` to reach there. So total time of `O(n)`.

And sum all the times together - `O(n)`.

Comment: can you explain a bit about what it means to add a int to each element?

Comment: @KaiweiLuo you need to remember for each element where it came from. So in @taurus05 answer this is done using an external dictionary that match every item to its list. The solution I suggest is to add a metadata to each element instead - the `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Using dictonary in Python, this can be accomplished very easily.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
a = [[9,2,5],[6,3,7],[1,8,4]]  #3 unsorted lists with 3 elements in each.
​
key_dict = dict()            # create a dictonary
​
for i in range(len(a)):      # iterate over each nested-list
    for val in a[i]:         # iterate over each element of the nested list
        key_dict[val] = i    # each element in dict contains the index of the nested list 
                             # it belongs to as a value, the key is the element itself
​
​
sorted_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(key_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[0])) #sorting elements collectively
​
new_list = [[] for i in range(3)]       # you can change it to number of nested lists present.
​
for k, v in sorted_dict.items():
    new_list[v].append(k)
print(new_list)     # Output : [[2, 5, 9], [3, 6, 7], [1, 4, 8]]
```

Except Sorting the elements, each step takes `O(n)` time to run, and this is excatly what you were expecting.